# image slider using explode function

Tags: php, css

I'm working on a product display slider which displays product images from database 
Now I am trying to use explode function to display one by one

problem is that all images a showing in one go rather then one by one

here is the code

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-5 grid">     
        <div class="flexslider">
        <?php $photos = explode(',',$products['image']);
                foreach($photos as $photo):?>
              <ul class="slides">
                <li data-thumb="<?= $photo; ?>">
                    <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="<?= $photo; ?>" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you may want your `ul` outside of the foreach. What is in your $products ['image']?